# Password Field does not Exclude - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to remove password1 field from my form. But it not excludeing. Even i don't want to delete password field just want to disable from form.

Forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    password2 = None
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name', 'email']
        exclude = ['password1',]
```

Comment: You have first_name last_name and email in your fields. so it will show these three only when you use modelform. No need to exclude. And also it is password not password1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `UserRegisterForm`

```
new_user = f.save(commit=True)
new_user.password = new_user.set_password('sdfasd')
```

and in `forms.py`

```
class UserRegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', )
```

Comment: oh yeah Thanks it Worked